# UWP wrap sqlite insert queries into sql transaction

Tags: c#, visual-studio, sqlite, win-universal-app

I am trying to insert some csv style file.txt content to a local `SQLite` dataBase, I handle file reading, content process and get some strings:

```
INSERT OR REPLACE INTO mytab (id,name,adress) VALUES(1,john,adress1)
INSERT OR REPLACE INTO mytab (id,name,adress) VALUES(2,marry,adress2)
INSERT OR REPLACE INTO mytab (id,name,adress) VALUES(3,lama,ruadress3)
//...
```

Now I want to open an sqlite transaction, do all this inserts and then to close transaction. I am using `SQLite.Net-PCL` and `SQLite for Universal App Platform`, how can I do that?

I tryed to open a connection like this:

```
var sqlpath = Path.Combine(ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.Path, "Mydb.sqlite");
SQLiteConnection conn = new SQLiteConnection(new SQLitePlatformWinRT(), sqlpath);

//I'am trying to open transaction - but get ERROR -> SQLiteCommand does not contain contstructor that takes 2 arguments
 SQLiteCommand cmd = new SQLiteCommand("BEGIN", conn);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `SQLiteConnection` class in `SQLite.Net-PCL` have `BeginTransaction`, `Commit` and `Rollback` methods, so you can wrap commands between BeginTransaction and Commit:

```
// Open connection
SQLiteConnection conn = new SQLiteConnection(new SQLitePlatformWinRT(), sqlpath);
try {
   // Start transaction
   conn.BeginTransaction();
   try {
      // Execute commands...
      // Commit transaction
      conn.Commit();
   }
   catch (Exception) {
      // Rollback transaction
      conn.Rollback();
   }
}
finally {
   // Close connection
   conn.Close();
}
```

Comment: Shouldn't we access the database in an async way? If so how to do that? - Thanks

Comment: @SurenSaluka There is an async version of the SQLiteConnection class, SQLiteAsyncConnection.

Comment: I’m using the SQLite PCL but I can’t find the async operations. Am I missing anything?

Comment: Please consider answering my question here. https://stackoverflow.com/q/56361654/776075